# How to match a string after a specific string using RegEx (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

Here's a sequence:

```
<h>blue</h>
<td>Water</td>
<h>red</h>
<td>Apple</td>
<h>yellow</h>
<td>Sun</td>
```

I would like to use RegEx to find the first occurence of `<td>` after the string `red`.
I tried `(?<=red)(<td>)([\s\S]*?)(</td>)` but I return nothing. I am not sure why.
The closest I had was `(?<=red)([\s\S]*?)(</td>)` but it adds the white spaces and the tags.

I know I could do this using indexing and substring manipulation but I'd rather use RegEx.

Is there a way to do this?
I am specifically looking for C# specific solutions.

```
string s = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=red)([\s\S]*?)(</td>)");
```

Comment: Don't use regex for this.  Use an XML parser, maybe something like XPath.

Comment: what is the c# code surrounding your regex?

Comment: @Isaac string s = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=red)([\s\S]*?)(</td>)");

Comment: Code in comments doesn't exist. Instead, [edit] your question and add it there.

Comment: Assuming your “sequence” is actually XML and you are looking for any element containing “red” and you are actually looking for the `<td>` element and not just whether one exists, you can use `XDocument.Parse(yourXml).Root.Elements().First(e => e.Value=="red").ElementsAfterSelf("td").First()`. If any of those assumptions are incorrect please clarify your question.

Comment: I have a problem and i want to solve it with regex, now i have 2 problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do **really really really** want to use **regex** to solve this problem use:

```
(?<=red</h>\s*<td>)([^<]*)
```

[image]

It uses `(?<=…)` positive lookbehind and will match and capture the string after \s* until it reaches a `<`.

**However I would really really really recommend to use an xml parser to do this kind of operations!!!**

Comment: Thank you very much Allan, this answers my question fully! It is hard to get RegEx answers but when I do, they're the best!.

Comment: @Phil you are very fortunate this “fully” answers your question since it does not do what you asked. You asked for the “ first occurence of `<td>` after the string `red`” and this expression returns a `<td>` after whitespace after the string `red</h>`. Note this expression may not work with XML because XML need not be delimited with whitespace. In the future please describe your problem accurately.

Comment: @Dour High Arch. The problem was well described and answered fully well by Allan who provided the appropriate RegEx code. You did not. I ran the pattern through 10 000 lines of text and it was 100% accurate.